# How to use alterColumn to change the values of an ENUM field in a DB Migration

Tags: plugin-development, migration, createcommand

I need to add a value to my plugin database for an ENUM field but I am struggling to find the correct syntax for the alterColumn method.

I want to do this but with alterColumn if possible?

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE columnName columnName ENUM('existingOption1', 'existingOption2', 'newOption') DEFAULT NULL;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$this->alterColumn('tableName', 'columnName', "enum('existingOption1','existingOption2','newOption') NULL");
```